# Custom AudioNode Automation

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm looking for a way to create a custom AudioNode and be able to modulate its AudioParams like a native AudioNode. i.e. LFO.connect.(gainNode.gain).

In my case, I want to create a CrossFader node (A,B) and be able to modulate its mix between A,B using an OscillatorNode.

I have this as a functional but un-automatable starting point:

```
function crossFade(val, max, inputA, inputB) {
    var x = parseInt(val) / parseInt(max),
        gain1 = Math.cos(x * 0.5 * Math.PI),
        gain2 = Math.cos((1.0 - x) * 0.5 * Math.PI);

    inputA.gain.value = gain1;
    inputB.gain.value = gain2;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd think you want something like this:

```
function CrossFade(){
    this.inputA = context.createGain();
    this.inputB = context.createGain();
    this.fade = function(val, max) {
        var x = parseInt(val) / parseInt(max),
            gain1 = Math.cos(x * 0.5 * Math.PI),
            gain2 = Math.cos((1.0 - x) * 0.5 * Math.PI);

        inputA.gain.value = gain1;
        inputB.gain.value = gain2;
    }
}
```

That way, when you do `var c = new CrossFade()` you can connect your tracks to either c.inputA or c.inputB. You're then free to connect your modulator to these gain AudioNodes as you see fit (you'd probably have to use a script processor node to invert the phase of the oscillator if you want to use a single oscillator as the modulator of both inputs at once).

(Note that you should probably put the fade method on the prototype, but I used the this-syntax here for brevity.)

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to automate your cross fader.  Create buffer source that consists of a linear ramp.  Create two WaveShaperNodes where the curve matches your Math.cos formulas.  Connect the buffer source to each WaveShaperNode and connect the output of each WaveShaperNode to the gain nodes you want to automate. Start the source node at the point in time where you want the cross fader to start.

I think this will do what you want.